# How does one nest only one level deep in LessCSS?

Tags: css, less

I'm trying to do

```
li > a
```

with LessCSS nesting. Is this possible?

I initially thought maybe something like

```
li {
    > a {  }
}
```

But this didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like that *should* work, but try adding an `&` just before the combinator:

```
li {
    & > a {  }
}
```

The [LESS web site](http://lesscss.org) doesn't  mention the use of `&` when nesting selectors with other combinators, but then again the documentation there isn't the best I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

The LESS CSS website doesn't mention these things which is quite confusing. But all kinds of selectors actually work (even without the *&* sign). You can type any of the CSS selectors and they will compile properly:

```
p {
    > a { }
    + .class { }
    ~ #named { }
}
```

You need the *&* sign when writing rules for psedudo-classes/elements:

```
a {
    &:hover { }
    &:last-child { }
    &::before { }
}
```

Are you sure it's not working? Are you using the latest version of LESS?